# Apache 410 a URL Without Affecting Sub Paths

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to kill a URL, so in my `.htaccess` file, I put:

```
Redirect    410 /my-path
```

It works.

If I try to visit:

```
https://www.example.com/my-path
```

I get:

> **Gone**
> The requested resource is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address.
> Please remove all references to this resource.

The problem is it also affects all sub paths, so if I try to visit `https://www.example.com/my-path/sub-path`, I also get the above "Gone" message.

How can I kill off just ONE specific path to my site with a 410?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `RedirectMatch` directive instead, which matches using a regex, rather than prefix-matching:

```
RedirectMatch 410 ^/my-path/?$
```

However, if you are already using mod_rewrite for other redirects/rewrites then you should probably use mod_rewrite instead to avoid potential conflicts. For example, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^my-path/?$ - [G]
```

`G` is a shortcut for `R=410`.

Reference:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: I used your RedirectMatch suggestion. Thank you.